# Bootstrap table strict search for only 1 column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) for my website and data has a field `gender` with all other 20 fields.

I have enabled `data-search` for this table and `data-filter-control="select"` for `gender` field as it only has 2 options.

Now i have `strictSearch=false` for the table so users can search easily but that causes problem with `gender` fields as both gender has word `male` in it so when i search for only `male` it displyas both gender.

I want to enable strich search for `gender` column only.

What is the solution for that??

Comment: is that datatable? or can you show us the link of what you are using?

Comment: @claudios i am using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)

Comment: what happens if you change `strictSearch=true`?

Comment: @claudios `data-strict-search="true"` options is for full table. So it will be strict search for all columns. I only want strict search for only `gender`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the default search since you wanted a custom search functionality by using given code.

text: the search text

Example usage:

```
function customSearch(text) {
        //Search logic here.
        //You must use `this.data` array in order to filter the data. NO use `this.options.data`.
    }
```

You may find it [here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options).

Comment: its for all columns and not for particular column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the filter-control extension, so you can use following column option: `data-filter-strict-search="true"`

https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/filter-control/#filterstrictsearch